# Error in Google Spreadsheet Inner Queries

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have the following table in Google Spreadsheet. I want to select items from column `B` but based on a condition that only these rows are selected where the values of columns `A` and `D` match.

[image]

I constructed the following query to check that a syntax is correct:

```
=CONCATENATE("Select B where A matches '.*"&TEXTJOIN(".*|.*"; true; query(D2:D; "Select D"));".*'")
```

Executing this gives the following result:

```
Select B where A matches '.*Item1.*|.*Item2.*|.*Item3.*'
```

When I now use this syntax in a query, then the result is correct: `1 2 3`

```
=query(A2:B; "Select B where A matches '.*Item1.*|.*Item2.*|.*Item3.*'")
```

But when putting all this together I got the following error message. Why is that?

```
=query(A2:B; "Select B where A matches '.*"&TEXTJOIN(".*|.*"; true; query(D2:D; "Select D"));".*'")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

unless you somehow query down the D column you don't need to use query on D column because textjoin will remove blanks. and the culprit in your formula was the last semicolon `;".*'"` where it should be `&".*'"`

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:B; 
 "select B 
  where A matches '.*"&TEXTJOIN(".*|.*"; 1; D2:D)&".*'"; 0)
```

Comment: Thanx, now it works! But why is the last zero needed in a statement? It seems that it works without it also.

Comment: @JaneMänd just for extra safety. sometimes query fails to autodetect header rows if 3rd parameter (0) is not specified

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

You put an `;` instead of `&` at the end:

`=query(A2:B; "Select B where A matches '.*"&TEXTJOIN(".*|.*"; true; query(D2:D; "Select D"))&".*'")`

**Explanation:**

This `".*'"` was passed as a third argument. But the third argument (which is optional) needs to be of type number.

See the [official documentation](http://QUERY) for more details:

[image]